# Using a Loop Inside a Function

Tags: php, function, while-loop

I'm still learning functions and how they work. I know what I'm doing wrong just not how to fix it. I am writing a function to pull image data out of a database and return it onto the screen. It works but if there is more than one image it will return the last image only. I know the problem is that `$project_image` is only returning the last image because of the way the while loop works but my question is how can i either not use a while loop or make it add more than one image to the `$project_image` variable.

**Abridged Function**

```
   function get_project_image($id,$type="thumb",$src="false",$limit=1){
    if($type =="main"){
        $project_image_qry = mysql_query(" SELECT i_name FROM `project_images` WHERE i_project_id = '$id' AND i_type= '2' LIMIT $limit " ) or die(mysql_error());
        $project_image="";
            while($project_image_row = mysql_fetch_array($project_image_qry)) {
            $project_image_result =  mysql_fetch_array ($project_image_qry);    

                if($src=="true"){
                    $project_image .= '<img src="'.admin_settings('site_url').admin_settings('image_main_dir').'/'.$project_image_result['i_name'].'" alt="project_image"/>';   
                    }
                else{
                    $project_image .= $project_image_result['i_name'];
                    }
            }
        }
    return $project_image;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `while` condition is fine, but you seem to be fetching twice, in `$project_image_row` and `$project_image_result`, so you're going to be skipping every other image. Just fetch the array once (in the while loop is good), and use `$project_image_result` instead of `$project_image_row` within the loop to refer to that array:

```
while($project_image_result = mysql_fetch_array($project_image_qry)) {
    if($src=="true"){
        $project_image .= '<img src="'.admin_settings('site_url').admin_settings('image_main_dir').'/'.$project_image_result['i_name'].'" alt="project_image"/>';   
    }
    else{
        $project_image .= $project_image_result['i_name'];
    }
}
```

Also, it seems like by default you told it to only request one image from the database. You have a default parameter `$limit=1`, and you use an SQL `LIMIT` to filter the results, so unless you pass a fourth argument to `get_project_image` the `mysql_query` is only going to return one result (you didn't include the call to `get_project_image`, so I'm not sure if you handled that or not

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH! That worked great. I belive you ment to use `$project_image_result` instead of `$project_image_row` in your example `while` loop above, no biggie. 

Also with regards to your comment about the default limit my function call looks like `echo get_project_image($project_row['p_id'],"main","true",2);` I limit it to one by default as the other two image types only have one image per type. Thanks again.