# using loop inside php function and returning result using JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

looking at the php function bellow i have this scenario: there is more then one IdUserfollow each id have to be passed on result2 and all the retrieved values have to be combined and returned to Xcode

```
 function viewhome($IdUser){
    $result1 = query("SELECT * FROM follows  WHERE IdUser = '%s' ", $IdUser);
    $IUser = $result['result'][0]['IdUserfollow'];
    $result2 = query("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE IdUser = '%s' ORDER BY IdPhoto DESC LIMIT    50", $IUser);
    print json_encode($result2);
}
```

how can i do that.

i sow this problem [Using a Loop Inside a Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115607/using-a-loop-inside-a-function) which was similar to mine but still I'm confused. considering that my return will be using JSON and also i don't know how to set the loop limit from the first query result. is it possible that i will have to do two functions, the first one will return the number of repetition and the second one will only have the loop and return the result? if yes then how can i combine two results - or whatever the value of the repetition is- and send it back using json

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may collect all retrieving data from second query to result array like this:

```
 function viewhome($IdUser){
    $result1 = query("SELECT * FROM follows  WHERE IdUser = '%s' ", $IdUser);
    $IUser = $result['result'][0]['IdUserfollow'];
    $result = array();
    foreach ( $result['result'] as $data ) {
       $result[] = query("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE IdUser = '%s' ORDER BY IdPhoto DESC LIMIT    50", $data['idUserfollow']);
    }
    print json_encode($result); // all the results for each IdUserfollow from first query
}
```

But all the same, I advice you not to send several queries to DB, but build only one query, wich solve you problem.